# Does the following validation mean that the field cannot be null? ( @Size annotation )

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have the following property in my Spring MVC Form bean using the `javax.validation.constraints` to validate the form bean as follows:

```
public class MyForm {
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    private String postcode;

    // getter and setter for postcode.
}
```

My question is: Does the `@Size(min = 2)` mean that the property cannot be `null` as it will always require a length greater than 2. The reason why I say that is because there is a `@NotNull` constraint in the same package and therefore does that make the `@NotNull` constraint redundant if I should use it in the above bean.

Comment: "Nulls are considered valid" says in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMax.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of the annotation **Size** (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) 
 
You can read "*null elements are considered valid.*" 
Therefore you need to specify **@NotNull** on the top of your field.
You have two alternatives:

```
@NotNull 
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
private Integer age;
```

Or like Riccardo F. suggested:

```
@NotNull @Min(13) @Max(110)
private Integer age;
```

Comment: Slight correction to your answer: `@Size` doesn't apply to Integers. So you use `@Min` and `@Max` for Integers, but use `@Size` for Strings. See supported types for `@Size` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html

Answer (score 2):

**@NotNull** is used for text fields too but you can use them together like

> ```
> @NotNull @Min(13) @Max(110)
> private Integer age;
> ```

That means *age* cannot be null and must be a value between 13 and 100 and

> ```
> @NotNull
> private Gender gender;
> ```

Means the *gender* cannot be null

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation for `@Size`

> `null` elements are considered valid.

For reference **hibernate-validation** actual `@Size` implementations are in:

> `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SizeValidator`

So specify `@NotNull` anyway.